# How to filter out already selected items from dropdown control in LightSwitch?

Tags: drop-down-menu, visual-studio-lightswitch

What I am trying to achive is the following:
I have a drop down list with some values from a database. I have some Materials, that I associate to WorkingUnits. So I am able to assign as many Materials as I want to a WorkingUnit, as well as have one and the same material assigned to two different WorkingUnits (in case I want to do so). So far so good, but what I want to achive as extra, is to filter out the already selected materials per working unit so that the user cannot select them again.

Improvised tables relationship:

```
|Materials|1 --------- * |MaterialWorkingUnitMap| * ----------- 1 |WorkingUnit|
```

I might be asking for something trivial, but I cannot figure this out so far. Are the relationships wrong in your according to the described behaviour? According to me they make sense, but I am completely new to LightSwitch.

Another solution would be to also include some validation in case the user selects one and the same material. This is the less desired approach, but I guess it satisfies me as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the command that adds a selected material item to the MaterialWorkingUnitMap, add some code that removes the selected record from the Material collection.  With Lightswitch's databinding, that should immediately visibly remove the Material record from the view.  However, when you call SaveChanges, this will cause a deletion of those material records from the database, which I don't imagine you want to do.  So to prevent that, in the SaveChanges pipeline, you can call DiscardChanges on the deleted Material records.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps.

Go to your Materials table and create a new query called "UnusedMaterialsByWorkingUnit"
In this query, add 1 parameter:   Parameter WorkingUnitID of type Integer. 
Go to the Write Code dropdown and select  "UnusedMaterialsByWorkingUnit_PreprocessQuery"

Make your PreprocessQuery look like this:

```
partial void UnusedMaterialsByWorkingUnit_PreprocessQuery(int? WorkingUnitID, ref IQueryable<Material> query)

{
    query = from material in query
            where !material.MaterialWorkingUnitMaps.Any(c => c.WorkingUnit.Id == WorkingUnitID)
            select material;
}
```

Go to your LIghtswitch screen where you have your dropdown. 
Add Data Item... and select the UnusedMaterialsByWorkingUnit query. 
On the left of the screen, click on the WorkingUnitID which is in the query and databind it to WorkingUnit.ID that is loaded on the screen. 
Go to your dropdown and select the UnusedMaterialsByWorkingUnit collection as the source.

Let me know if this works!

Comment: This actually worked for me in VS2015. To clarify some of your instructions; Once you've created the new query and added it as a data item, you have to bind the /parameter/ for the query to your property from the mapping table. Then, click the dropdown and in the properties window, find "Choices" and change the selection there to the new query. I didn't have anything called "source". Caveat; if you add multiple things in one save, you can still potentially add duplicates since the "unused" data in the list doesn't update until you save. But its better than the default.

Comment: This is a much more thorough answer than the accepted one and won't accidentally delete records if you forget to discard changes. Worked beautifully for me (VS 2015, LS HTML)